# remove backslash only from quote character using sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I have string: `this is a [\"sample\"] sample\'s.`

What would be the correct way to remove backslashes from the double quote, preserving the double quote.

Expected output: `this is a ["sample"] sample\'s.`

I've tested: `sed -i 's/\\\"//g' file.txt` which is removing the `"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command is almost correct. You just forgot to substitute with a double quote:

```
sed -i 's/\\"/"/g' file.txt
```

`sed`'s [`s` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) substitutes the first part (between `/` here) with the second part. The `g` flag repeats the operation throughout the line. Your mistake was that the second part was empty, thus effectively deleting the whole `\"` string.

BTW, escaping the double quote is not necessary since your `sed` command is inside single quotes.

Comment: So to break that down, the regex is searching for \" and replacing that with "?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Do you need more details on how the `s` command works?

Comment: Sure if you want to provide a reference. Thanks for the help btw!